# passing this as a parameter in javascript

Tags: javascript, this, parameter-passing, imagebutton

I want to pass this as a parameter for a function in javascript , as see below :

```
<input type="image" class="img_btn" id="img" src="img1.jpg" onclick="edit(this);"/>
```

and my edit function :

```
function edit(javad) {
    if (x == 1) {
        javad.src = "img1.jpg";
        x = 0;
    } else {
        javad.src = "img2.jpg";
        x = 1;
    }
}
```

and default value for x is 1.

But it does not work ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where did you declare x in your code ? (is it a global variable ?)

Comment: You seem to not be aware of [**the browser's error console**](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)...

Comment: Consider learning to use the browser's javascript console so you can debug these problems yourself, it will save a lot of time in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve problem :)

it does not works true because of var x is global, and in per call function it set to 1.Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Strings in JavaScript are quoted so you have to put your file name in quotes

```
javad.src="img1.jpg";
```

---

Your code works except if x is 1 by default then when you click the input you would set its source to the same image, if you click it again it will change. If x is 0 by default it will change on the first click.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/qJgSe/)

Answer (score 2):

the code you have thinks you are setting the `src` to an object because you have not quotes.

```
javad.src = "img2.jpg";
```

should do the trick.